# Changing a VBA CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll to a lower memory footprint

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a huge CSV file that has to be transposed before loading into an Excel spreadsheet (due to Excel 2010 limitations).  This code seemed to do the trick until the file got big (>30mb).

```
Sub transpose_delimited_file(sheet, filename, skip_columns, delimiter)
Dim temp As String
Dim i As Long, x


temp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filename, 1).ReadAll
x = Split(temp, vbCrLf): temp = ""
For i = 0 To UBound(x) - 1
    y = Split(x(i), delimiter)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet).Cells(1, i + 1 + skip_columns).Resize(UBound(y) + 1).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(y)
Next
```

So how can the above code be changed to avoid an out of memory error?  Is there a way to change the `ReadAll` to just read X number of lines at a time then transpose and paste in the worksheet to keep the memory free?  Much appreciated.

Comment: @A.S.H are you saying to call .exe / .bat files from Excel to split the file prior to loading and then reassemble the subsets and paste into the Excel file?

Comment: Matt I think that the best attempt is to read line by line. This is what the code in my answer does. I tested it on small files but it should be ok on large ones. Try it and tell me if it still has problems.

Comment: The text file  is  so big and  transpose limited number of row to 65536 row.

Comment: wich line errors?

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier the `temp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filename, 1).ReadAll` line errors.  A.S.H answered the question though and it seems way faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best attempt is to read the file line by line and paste them as columns in the destination sheet. The following code using raw I/O should achieve it:

```
Sub transposeDelimitedFile(ByRef sh As Worksheet, ByVal fName As String, _
                           Optional ByVal startCol As Long = 1, _
                           Optional ByVal delim As String = ",")
  Dim sLine As String, ar

  Open fName For Input As #1
  Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, sLine
    ar = Split(sLine, delim)
    sh.Columns(startCol).Resize(UBound(ar) + 1).value = Application.Transpose(ar)
    startCol = startCol + 1
  Loop
  Close #1
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Test()
  transposeDelimitedFile Worksheets("Sheet1"), "C:\SO\SO.CSV", 6, ","
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, this is way faster than the method I was using before (although not quite a fair comparison as I'm directly on the network - still a 32MB file read and transposed in about 1 minute is great.

Comment: @Matt It's great that you confirmed that, as I could not test it myself on a huge file but only expected it to be less resource consuming than reading the whole file at once. :)